# Table of contents hyperlink refers to the wrong page when the section starts at the top of the page, when using usepackage{titlesec}

Tags: hyperref, titlesec

long but accurate title. When I include the titlesec package (even without really using it), and when a section start at the top of a new page, the table of contents links to the previous one.
Here is a MWE. When clicking on "Section Two" in the toc, I arrive to the previous page (Section One). If I remove `\usepackage{titlesec}` **OR** if I add/remove several sentences in Section One to make Section Two not start at the top, the problem disappear.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{titlesec}



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage 

\section{Section One}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est.

\section{Section Two}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) In general and [with few exceptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/), `\usepackage{hyperref}` must be loaded **last** in your preamble, because `hyperref` has to adjust itself to all your other packages. This is all the more true with a package like `titlesec`, which redefines commands such as `\section`. In your example, after `hyperref` does its work, `titlesec` undoes it to some extent. – Try loading `\usepackage{titlesec} \usepackage{hyperref}` in this order and see if the problem disappears.

Comment: perfect ! thanks a lot, it indeed solved my problem. I dont know how I can accept your answer and flag my question "solved' or something like that ?

Comment: You ask @marquinho to create an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is a prime example of why `hyperref` should be the last of your loaded packages in the preamble,

> to give it a fighting chance of not being
> over-written, since its job is to redefine many LATEX commands

according to the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf#page=6).

`hyperref` redefines LaTeX internals and macros such as `\section`, `\footnote` and other things that should perform as hyperlinks or hypertargets. For this to work, `hyperref` has to adjust itself to all other packages that may have previously redefined those same internals.

`titlesec` is one of these packages: it alters the appearance and function of sectioning commands such as `\section` via a series of redefinitions. The definitions in `titlesec` have the potential to *overwrite* those made by `hyperref`, effectively undoing some of the work done by it – which results in a loss of hypertext functionality.

To avoid this, `hyperref` must be loaded *after* `titlesec` (and similar packages). Reversing the order of the two packages in the preamble solves your problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
```

There are but a few exceptions to this rule: see [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/)